# Component returning nested React Elements not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a default component *Collection* which uses a sub-component called *RenderCollectionPieces* to display UI elements. I can't figure out why I am able to see the data for `image.name` in the console but **not able to see the UI elements display**.

Additional information:

- There are no errors in the console
- If I replace `<p>{image.name}</p>` with `<p>TESTING</p>`, still nothing shows.
- columnOrg is a list of lists
- each list in columnOrg is a list of maps with some attributes

Index.js:

```
const RenderCollectionPieces = () => {
  const {collectionId} = useParams();  
  let listOfImageObjects = collectionMap[collectionId];
  let imagesPerColumn = Math.ceil(listOfImageObjects.length / 4);
  let columnOrg = [];

  while (columnOrg.length < 4){
    if(imagesPerColumn > listOfImageObjects.length){
      imagesPerColumn = listOfImageObjects.length;
    }
    columnOrg.push(listOfImageObjects.splice(0,imagesPerColumn))
  }
 
  let collectionList = columnOrg.map((col) => {
        return(            
            <Grid item sm={3}>
              {
                col.map((image) => {
                  console.log(image.name)
                  return(
                    <p>{image.name}</p>
                  )
                })
              }
            </Grid>
        )
    });
  return collectionList;
};

const Collection = ({ match }) => {
  const {collectionId} = useParams();
  return(
    <Box sx={{ background:'white'}}>
      <Grid container>           
        <RenderCollectionPieces />          
      </Grid>
  </Box>
  )
};

export default Collection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by using useEffect/useState as recommended by [Samuel Oleksak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4760478/samuel-olek%C5%A1%C3%A1k)

```
    const RenderCollectionPieces = (props) => {
    const [columnOrg, setColumnOrg] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
    let columnSetup = []
    let listOfImageObjects = collectionMap[props.collectionId.collectionId];
    let imagesPerColumn = Math.ceil(listOfImageObjects.length / 4);
    
    while (columnSetup.length < 4){
      if(imagesPerColumn > listOfImageObjects.length){
        imagesPerColumn = listOfImageObjects.length;
      }
      columnSetup.push(listOfImageObjects.splice(0,imagesPerColumn))
    }
    setColumnOrg(columnSetup);
  },[]);
  
  return (
      columnOrg.map((column) => {
        return (
          <Grid item sm={3}>
            {
              column.map((image) => {
                return (<img src={image.src} alt={image.name}/>)
              })
            }
          </Grid>
        )
      })
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding state management in React. Every variable you want to remember inbetween component re-renders should be included in state using `useState` hook. If you want to perform something initially like your while loop, use it inside `useEffect` hook.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [myCounter, setMyCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("This will be performed at the start");
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => setMyCounter(myCounter++)} />
      You clicked {myCounter} times
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

If you are unfamiliar with `useState` and `useEffect` hooks I recommend learning about them first to understand how React manages state and re-renders: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Are these hooks really necessary? All I want the component to do is loop through a couple of lists and return items within the content of UI elements. Seems like the hooks would be more useful if you are expecting the user to interact with the UI. I am simply looking to load the items and their relative attributes on the screen.

Comment: Can you reply back with an answer that works using useEffect?